# Loop until matrix is full?

Tags: matrix

I have a conditional statement that adds row of binary values from matrix A to matrix B. I want to put this in a loop so that it continues to add rows from matrix A until matrix B is full. Currently matrix B is initialized as 10 by 10 matrix of zeros. Do I need to initialize matrix B differently in order to create this condition or is there a way of doing it as is?

Below is roughly how my code looks so far

```
from random import sample
import numpy as np

matrixA = np.random.randint(2, size=(10,10))

matrixB = np.zeros((10,10))

x, y = sample(range(1, 10), k=2)

if someCondition:
    matrixB = np.append(matrixB, [matrixA[x]], axis=0)
else:
    matrixB = np.append(matrixB, [matrixA[y]], axis=0)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: well, the while loop runs until a condition is met, which could, in your case, be the matrix B being full.

Comment: So, you are adding values from matrix A to matrix B row-wise, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [mre],  [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I was in the process of copying my code as you wrote this @wwii

Comment: `sample(range(1, 10), k=2)` - what is `sample`?

Comment: @JFrench .. not my dv

Comment: The if appends the row matrixA[x] and the else  appends the row matrixA[y]. I think you misread, I removed the first statement.  Thanks for all your concern:)  @wwii

Comment: `until matrix B is full` - If you are **adding** rows how do you know when it is *full*?

Comment: Please make sure your question is clear about what you are trying to accomplish; use smaller arrays (maybe 5x5) so you can show what you are starting with and what you expect for your result (copy the *data* as text and format it as code in your question); also try to explain why your solution is deficient. - even with your edited question it is unclear what your desired result is. Your example has `if someCondition:`  and you ask `...in order to create this condition...` that is confusing me at least.

Comment: The question has been closed. I voted to reopen but it may be a while before there are enough reopen votes. You can opt to revise this question and wait for enough reopen votes or leave this question as-is and ask a new (clearer) question or delete and and ask a new (clearer) question.

Comment: As a beginner coder it is sometimes hard to articulate what I am trying to achieve. Obviously this will improve with practice. Constant criticism and comments highlighting errors although you believe is helpful, it is actually very demotivating. Especially when you are editing previous comments where you have clearly just misread the code and are trying to find any fault. Just a suggestion for the future maybe don't be so critical. We do not all have the same level of experience! Thanks anyways @wwii

Comment: Or maybe don't delete:  [Should I delete my question if it is closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256559/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-closed) ... or maybe you cannot delete [How to delete an answered question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255012/how-to-delete-an-answered-question)

Comment: .. Often examples in questions use functions or methods or classes that are not shown in the example. Without knowing what they are how can we know what they do? I wasn't drawing attention to a mistake I was asking what it was so I could interpret your example.

Comment: I just assumed that was a common import from random that most users would be familiar with. I can see you were trying to help. A lot of comments highlighting errors in a short space of time can be misinterpreted, especially when comments regarding misread code are not acknowledge.I understand it wasn't intended that way. Happy coding;) @wwii

Comment: I similarly imagine some people approach helping others with kindness, as opposed to condescendingly error picking without taking accountability for their own misinterpretations.    @wwii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a loop for it. It is really easy to just do it using smart indexing. For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20,10))
B = np.empty((10, 10))
print(A)
# Copy till the row that satisfies your conditions. Here I assume it to be 10
B = A[:10, :]
print(B)
```